# How to add friction to a Wheel of Fortune in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

First of all I am new to unity as will as C#. I want to create a Wheel of Fortune for my game using C# where you can rotate it with the mouse. I wrote this code in C# - it works well, the only problem is I don’t know how to add friction to it so that if I release the mouse button it still continues rotating and slows down until it is fully stopped (Just like a realistic Fortune Wheel).

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RotateCSharp : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int speed;
    public float lerpSpeed;
    float xDeg;
    float yDeg;
    Quaternion fromRotation;
    Quaternion toRotation;


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            xDeg -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed;
            fromRotation = transform.rotation;
            toRotation = Quaternion.Euler (yDeg,xDeg,0);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromRotation, toRotation, Time.deltaTime * lerpSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You should add C# and Unity tags to the question to get more answers.

Answer (score 1):

*Full Disclosure--I don't do Unity, and not much C#, but this is mostly math.*

Friction from sliding or rolling is almost exactly constant deceleration.  Deceleration is negative acceleration, and acceleration is (velocity change)/(elapsed time).

Figure out how long you want the wheel to spin at a the maximum initial angular speed you'll allow, and that speed/time ratio is your deceleration rate.  That's a constant for the wheel.

Now, in the code either before or after adjusting the angular position, decrease the speed by the deceleration rate * time interval, being careful not to overshoot 0:

```
if (speed > 0)
    speed = Math.max(0, speed - decelRate*Time.deltaTime);
else 
    speed = Math.min(0, speed + decelRate*Time.deltaTime);
```

That assumes that decelRate is a positive value, and will handle spins in either direction.

You may have to adjust the syntax a bit, but that's the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a behaviour that applies friction on a hinge joint. Here it is:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class JointFriction : MonoBehaviour {

  [Tooltip("mulitiplier for the angular velocity for the torque to apply.")]
  public float Friction = 0.4f;

  private HingeJoint _hinge;
  private Rigidbody _thisBody;
  private Rigidbody _connectedBody;
  private Vector3 _axis;  //local space

  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
    _hinge = GetComponent<HingeJoint>();
    _connectedBody = _hinge.connectedBody;
    _axis = _hinge.axis;

    _thisBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void FixedUpdate () {
    var angularV = _hinge.velocity;
    //Debug.Log("angularV " + angularV);
    var worldAxis = transform.TransformVector(_axis);
    var worldTorque = Friction * angularV * worldAxis;

    _thisBody.AddTorque(-worldTorque);
    _connectedBody.AddTorque(worldTorque);
  }
}
```

You can apply this as a separate behaviour to the object with the hinge joint, or you can take bits of it and incorporate them into your behaviour.

This code assumes the hinge joint has a connected rigidbody that it is rubbing against, if that is not the case, simply remove the lines that refer to the _connectedRigidbody.